# How to store Date in sql server in Indian Format using calender extender

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on a asp.net web application where i have to store date in sql server 2008 in Indian format that is "dd-MM-yyyy". I have calender extender to enter date in textbox then to store in sql.

The design is:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calStart" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate"
    PopupButtonID="imgvStartDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"></asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgvStartDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/iconCalendar.gif"
TabIndex="6" Style="margin-left: -0%; height: 18px;" />
```

In Code behind:-

```
Entity_SupplierPayment objSupplierPayment = new Entity_SupplierPayment();
    objSupplierPayment.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text.Trim(), format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

but it is showing error:--
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**1 - Set date**: convert Indian calendar format to Gregorian calendar format then store in database:

```
objSupplierPayment.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

**2 - Get date:** Read date from Database and convert to Indian format then show in GridView(assume cell 5 is DateTime field):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[5].Text)
       && e.Row.Cells[5].Text != "&nbsp;")
        e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[5].Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: sir it is showing the error:--String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: share existing date into textbox

Comment: when i select 28 september 2013 from calender extender then in the textbox is shows as:28/09/2013,,but during storing into a date type variable it causes error:-String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya(v=vs.90).aspx this might help you out.

Comment: @SunnySandeep - helped?

Comment: @SamieyMehdi but Sir it store date not in indian format.please help me in storing date in indian format

Comment: SunnySandeep - you can store date into database and for showing date in page  convert to indian.

Comment: later read from database then convert to indian then show in page

Comment: I have to all data in gridview.Then at time of reading i did it as--- protected void WizardGridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    Label lblEnd_Date = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblEnd_Date");                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        } but it showing error

Comment: Sunny Sandeep - you can convert date to indian and store to string field of database

Comment: in the database the date is stored as: 09/28/2013 12:00:00 AM.And when i used to convert this while reading by using your code above:- objSupplierPayment.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);  Then it shows error:--String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @SunnySandeep - helped